# stripe webhook can't get to work with rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webhooks

I have been trying really hard to get my webhook to work. I have tried both methods creating the controller and post route and using the stripe event gem. Both have failed me.

Can someone help with what I am doing wrong.

here is my controller for the webhook

```
class StripewebhooksController < ApplicationController
    # Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
    # See your keys here https://manage.stripe.com/account
    Stripe.api_key = "mystripe api key"

    require 'json'

    def receive

    data_json = JSON.parse(request.body.read)

    p data_json['data']['object']['customer']

    if data_json[:type] == "customer.subscription.deleted"
      cancel_subscription(data_json)
    end

     if data_json[:type] == "invoice.payment_succeeded"
      invoice_subscription(data_json)
    end

    end

    def cancel_subscription(data_json)
    @subscription = Subscription.find_by_stripe_customer_token(data_json['data']['object']['customer'])
    @subscription.update_attribute(:subscription_status, "inactive")
  end

  def invoice_subscription(data_json)
    @subscription = Subscription.find_by_stripe_customer_token(data_json['data']['object']['customer'])
    InvoiceMailer.invoice_subscription(@subscription).deliver
  end
end
```

I have this in my routes file and have raked routes and verified that the post route is there.

```
post 'stripewebhooks/receive'
```

stripe keeps giving me a 422 error.